# Multiple (word) selection with ctrl + (double) click in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Is is possible to create multiple cursors or selected multiple words by holding Control + left click (double left click) like in Sublime Text?

I'm running Atom 1.14.1 on Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it? It works the same way it works in Sublime Text.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can select a word with double click but when I hold ctrl + double click another word it doesn't do anything- Same thing when trying to create multiple cursors.

Comment: According to documentation it is supposed to work with ctrl-click: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/editing-and-deleting-text/#platform-linux

Comment: I found it, the conflict exists when Nuclide package (0.209.0) is enabled.
Nuclide has a Hiperclick feature that overrides ctrl + click functionality.
Thanks